# wordforms on sphinx

Tags: full-text-search, sphinx, full-text-indexing, fulltext-index

If I use the wordforms file, to a word like this:

television > tv

If i search for television, i'd get results with TV on it, but i also want to have television results, is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's how it works by default. But, you have to rebuild your index after changing the word forms. The mapping occurs at both index time and query time.

Comment: It's not working for me! When I search for television, it only brings "tv" results, no television at all!

Comment: did you rebuild the index using the word forms during indexing?